# Socket error:- Target machine refused connection to server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am getting a `WinError` in using socket.
It says the connection did not happen.

Here is the whole problem:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\IamOm\Downloads\Jarvis\socket_test.py", line 4, in 
c.connect(('localhost', 9999))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I have used this very simple and concise code for the program:-

That's the server.py file:-

```
import socket

c = socket.socket()
c.connect(('localhost', 9999))
```

This is my Client python file:-

```
import socket 
import threading
server = socket.socket()
s = "192.168.0.197"
server.bind((s, 9999))
server.listen(3)
print("Waiting for connections")
while True:
    c, addr = server.accept()
    print("Connected with ", addr)
    c.send(bytes("Welcome to Tooper", "utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is not the same as `192.168.0.197`. Try connecting to `192.168.0.197`.

Have a [quick read](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/what-is-localhost) about what `localhost` does. Basically it's a synonym for `127.0.0.1`, so it doesn't actually go to the 192 range network (yes I know this is oversymplifying it)